# Repeater control reverse order

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I'm working with a repeater control that displays my list items. Everytime i add an listitem it displays it on my repeater. But i want the repeater to display the latest added item at the top.

Any suggestions?

Right now i'm using this code:

```
    &nbsp;<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterContent" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h1><%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Title"].ToString() %></h1>
        <i><%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Date"].ToString()%></i><br/>   
        <i><%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Authors"].ToString()%></i><br/>

        <b><%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Contents"].ToString().Substring(0, 20)%></b><br/>

        <%--<i>...Read more</i>--%>

        <a href="<%# (new SPFieldUrlValue(((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Links"].ToString()).Url) %> " target="_blank"><%# (new SPFieldUrlValue(((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Links"].ToString()).Url) %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News"))
            {
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListCategory2.SelectedItem.Value);

                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();

                RepeaterContent.DataSource = items;
                RepeaterContent.DataBind();


                site.Dispose();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kristian,

Instead of

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News"))
{
     SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
     SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListCategory2.SelectedItem.Value);

     SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();

     RepeaterContent.DataSource = items;
     RepeaterContent.DataBind();

     site.Dispose();
 }
```

You can use:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News"))
{
     SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
     SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListCategory2.SelectedItem.Value);

     SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
     query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
     SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

     RepeaterContent.DataSource = items;
     RepeaterContent.DataBind();

     //site.Dispose();
 }
```

In this way the query will return data ordering them with last modified date descending order, also you don't need to Dispose site object... Since its already in using, it will get disposed after the using block!

I hope this helps...